# 404 page not found trying to navigate between pages in my Firebase app

Tags: firebase-hosting

I am building a Firebase app which runs correctly on my local server. But when deploy it to the Firebase Hosting I can't navigate between pages. After deploy it goes to the **index.html** page normally without problem

The problem is that when i clik on a link a get a 404 page. this how i am writting my link

```
<a href="secondPage.html"/>go to the second page </a>
```

I have my **index.html** and **secondPage.html** in the same directory

Comment: You'll need to share a bit more information, such as you firebase.json file and the URLs that you see in your browser's address bar both for index.html and secondPager.html.

Comment: Like Johnny 5, we NEED INPUT :)